# Shrinking in size when i use read() and write() in c sockets under linux

Tags: c, sockets, unix, file-io

I am programming a client server acting like downloader server. The client requests a file name from the server and then the server searches for the file if it exists or not. It works fine, but I observe something weird: when the client downloads the file requested from the server the size of downloaded file is not the same size of the original file.

Here is server code :

```
//  Server.c

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>     /* ANSI C header file */
#include <syslog.h>     /* for syslog() */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/* Following shortens all the typecasts of pointer arguments: */
#define SA      struct sockaddr
#define ListenQ 5
#define MAXLINE 1024    /* max text line length */

void error(char *msg);

/* to define mode for read() or write() */
mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP;
volatile sig_atomic_t eflag = 0;

int listenfd, connfd;   /* to define Server file descriptor */
int sockfd, fd;         /* to define Client file descriptor */
socklen_t clilen;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

char buffer[MAXLINE + 1];/* define buffer to send and recive with */
char _fileName[128];

int n;                  /*  to count from reading or wrinting in sockets */
int portno, stringlen;
int CmpValue, i;
int fd_Cli;
int daemon_proc;        /* set nonzero by daemon_init() */
uint8_t state;          /* define 1 byte state for  existance files in sever */
uint8_t secret;
//char fileName[128];
//char *fileTocmp="abc.txt";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /*Error checking for providing  appropirate port# */
    if (argc < 2)
        error("Error,no port provided, please enter the port#:22011 \n");

    /*open listening socket for server      note the Socket not socket */
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /*
     * to convert the port# from ascii to int to deal with it as int in
     * address structure
     */
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);

    //if(portno!=22011)
    //error(" please enter the port#:22011\n");

    // to zero the structre adress
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    // to bind the adresses to server
    bind(listenfd, (SA *) & servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    //to put the open socekt descrptor
    //to put the open socekt descrptor
    listen(listenfd, ListenQ);

    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...\n");




    for (;;) {
        clilen = sizeof(servaddr);

        /*
         * To handle Interupt which leads Accept() to interupt so here
         * to restart Accept()
         */
        if ((connfd = accept(listenfd, (SA *) & servaddr, &clilen)) < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;       /* back to for() */
            else
                error("accept error");
        }


        //bzero(&buffer,sizeof(buffer));
        //n=read(connfd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer));
        secret = 0x55;
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", secret);
        n = write(connfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("Sending Byte 0x55: (%x) to client (%s:%d) .\n", secret,
               inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr), ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));
        bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        n = read(connfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        printf("recived 0XAA is :%s from the client\n", buffer);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //this function to read and write from and to client

        printf("(%s:%d) connected.\n", inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr),
               ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));
        printf("waiting to provide file name From: (%s:%d) \n\n",
               inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr), ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));

        /*  to copy the file name to var fileName */
        //strncpy(fileName,fileTocmp,128);


        for (;;) {
            //bzero(&buffer,sizeof(buffer));
            //n=read(connfd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer));

            /////////////////////////////////////////////

            bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            n = read(connfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            printf("Recived file name :%s from client: (%s:%d)\n", buffer,
                   inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr), ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));
            //printf("\n");
            /*
             ///////////////////////////////////////////
             * Hehow to check if file exists in cre is the core of
             * comparing files at server if exists or not.
             ///////////////////////////////////////////
             */

            /*
             * compare the filename provided by User with the file exist
             * in server
             */
            //
            char *p;
            if ((p = strchr(buffer, '\n')))
                *p = 0;
            //CmpValue=access (buffer, F_OK|R_OK| W_OK);
            printf("the buffer now is : %s\n", buffer);
            /////////////////////////////
            strncpy(_fileName, buffer, 128);
            CmpValue = access(buffer, F_OK | R_OK);
            printf("the value of CMPaccess is : %d\n", CmpValue);

            if (CmpValue == 0) {
                bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                state = 1;
                /* to print the state=1 to buffer */
                sprintf(buffer, "%d", state);
                /* to print the state=1 to stdout */
                printf("Sending (%d) to the client : (%s:%d)\n", state,
                       inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr),
                       ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));
                printf("\n");
                /* to send the state=1 to client */
                n = write(connfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                ///////////////////////////////////////////
                printf("here is buffer before Func open is : %s\n",
                       buffer);

                fd = open(_fileName, O_RDONLY);
                /* To Handle the file descriptor error. */
                if (fd < 0) {
                    bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    printf
                        ("Sending Error value : %s (to client@ %s:%d) \n",
                         strerror(errno), inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr),
                         ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));

                    /* to print the ERROR to buffer */
                    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "ERROR(%d):%s", errno,
                             strerror(errno));
                    /* to send the ERROR to client */
                    n = write(connfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    if (n < 0) {
                        error("Error,Writing to socket \n");
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                int serverRead;
                while ((serverRead = read(fd, buffer, MAXLINE + 1) > 0)) {
                    /* to read from open file descriptor */
                    n = write(connfd, &buffer, n);
                    printf("------- the value of serverRead is : %d\n",
                           serverRead);
                    if (n < 0) {
                        error("Error,Reading from socket \n");
                    }
                }

                printf("hon ya 3rs 5lset writing ............\n");
                close(connfd);
                //printf("buffer now is : %s\n",buffer);
                //buffer[n] = '\0';
                //close(connfd);
                /*
                 * to send the buffer contents which "is from reading
                 * file descripotr" to client
                 */
            } else {
                bzero(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                state = 0;
                /* to print the state=0 to stdout */
                printf("Sending (%d) to the client : (%s:%d)\n", state,
                       inet_ntoa(servaddr.sin_addr),
                       ntohs(servaddr.sin_port));
                printf("\n");
                /* to print the state=0 to buffer */
                sprintf(buffer, "%d", state);
                n = write(connfd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                if (n < 0) {
                    error("Error,Writing to socket \n");
                }
                /* to send the state=0 to client */
            }

        } // end of for

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //this function to read and write from and to client


        //close(connfd);
    }
    //return 0;
}



void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}
```

So I haven't found a solution. Maybe it is related to the `open` and `read` implementations in Unix syscall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read some number of bytes from the file, that should be the number of bytes that you write. To me, it seems that you are writing some number of bytes that is not related to the number read at all:

```
            int serverRead;
            while ((serverRead = read(fd, buffer, MAXLINE + 1) > 0)) {
                /* to read from open file descriptor */
                n = write(connfd, &buffer, n);
                printf("------- the value of serverRead is : %d\n",
                       serverRead);
                if (n < 0) {
                    error("Error,Reading from socket \n");
                }
            }
```

Instead, you should change the way you call `write()` to write out `serverRead` bytes from `buffer`. Realize that writes can be shorter than the requested amount, so you need to protect against that with a loop around the `write()` call itself.

```
    ssize_t bytes_written = 0;
    while (bytes_written < serverRead) {
        n = write(connfd, buffer + bytes_written, serverRead - bytes_written);
        if (n > 0) {
            bytes_written += n;
            continue;
        }
        //...handle error
    }
```

Comment: I have not looked extensively for all problems in your code, and there is really too much code to do that anyway. If after fixing this you have other problems, please spend more time trying to work it out on your own to isolate just the part that you think is going wrong. If after doing so, you still get stuck, then post a question about that particular part.

Comment: thnx alot for your advice,but with your posted code , The read() function was ommited,so where can i put read() to read and write exactly without any loses in file size ???

Comment: @user2103930: I only fixed the call to `write()`, the rest of the code snippet I left unchanged, so didn't include it.

Comment: Thanx again ,but i tried the code you supplied ,but it fails with 0 byte reading???

Comment: 0 byte read on the file means you have reached the end of file. 0 byte read by the client means the server has closed the connection. These are basic concepts in I/O.